# Angularjs 2 show hide based on index

Tags: angular

I want to show hide div based on index

**`template`**

```
<tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="#item of itemList; #i = index">
        <td class="text-center">{{i+1}}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{item.name}}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{item.email}}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{item.city}}</td>
        <td class="text-center"><span (click)="removeItem($index)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" (click)="onSelect(i)"></span>
        <td [hidden]="IsHidden">{{item.orderid}}</td>
      </tr>
```

**`.ts`**

```
IsHidden= true;
    onSelect(index){
    console.log(this.itemList[index]);
     this.IsHidden = !this.IsHidden;
    }
```

When ever i click 1st one it show all **`tr hidden`** field.

How i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you need use `item.isHidden` instead of `this.isHidden`

```
 <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="#item of itemList; #i = index">
    <td class="text-center">{{i+1}}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{item.name}}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{item.email}}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{item.city}}</td>
    <td class="text-center"><span (click)="removeItem($index)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" (click)="onSelect(item)"></span>
    <td [hidden]="item.isHidden">{{item.orderid}}</td>
  </tr>
```

TS

```
onSelect(item){
   console.log(this.itemList[index]);
    item.IsHidden = !item.IsHidden;
}
```